# Prove that a function from a compact interval in R to itself has at least one fixed point without the intermediate value theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

Hey I'm studying for my qualifying exam using Carothers' Real Analysis. I came across this problem. Let $f: [a, b] \rightarrow [a, b]$ be continuous. Prove that $f$ has at least one fixed point without using the intermediate value theorem. I'm guessing it has something to do with compactness as it is in the compactness chapter. As a hint it says consider $g(x) = \lvert x - f(x)\rvert$. Now I know this function is continuous as it is a distance function, so $g([a,b])$ is a compact interval of $[0, b-a]$, but why must it contain 0?

Comment: Because $g(a)\le 0$ and $g(b)\ge 0$. (By the way, you can't deduce that $g([a,b])\subseteq[0,b-a]$. You _can_ deduce that $g([a,b])\subseteq[a-b,b-a]$.)

Comment: If $g(a) \leq 0$ then $g(a) = 0$ as $g$ is always positive, so I feel like that is incorrect. Also you can deduce that $g([a,b]) \subseteq [0, b-a]$ as $g$ is always positive so it can't actually attain values that are negative.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- I didn't notice the absolute value signs. But perhaps the proof goes better without them?

Comment: Sure you can use the intermediate value theorem without the absolute value signs, but the problem specifically states not to use it and to use the function with absolute values.

Comment: Hah I was just talking about this with my fiancée. Define a sequence $x_{n+1} = f(x_n) $ where $x_0 $ is in $[a, b] $. What can you conclude about the sequence? Using compactness, what can you do from there?

Comment: @CameronWilliams hmmm the sequence is contained in $[a,b]$ and as this is a compact set it contains a convergent subsequence. Since this subsequence is Cauchy $\lvert x_{n+1} - x_n \rvert < \epsilon$ for an arbitrary epsilon and a sufficiently large n, which implies that $\lvert f(x_n) - x_n\rvert < \epsilon$ for an arbitrary epsilon and a sufficiently large n. So the limit of this subsequence is the fixed point, and is in $[a,b]$ since it is closed? Is this right?

Comment: Yep that's correct.

Comment: @CameronWilliams hmmm I wonder if this is the solution that Carothers had in mind.

Comment: It's late here, so I apologize for possibly writing something stupid. If $f(x)\neq x$, for all $x$, then sets $A = \{ x \mid f(y) > y,\, \forall y\in [a,x] \}$ and $B = \{ x \mid f(x) < x \}$ are nonempty since they contain $a$ and $b$ respectively. Let $x_0 = \sup A$. But, $x_0$ is also a limit point of $B$ (or there would be an open interval around $x_0$ not intersecting $B$, contradicting the definition of $x_0$) so either $f(x_0) = x_0$, or $f$ has discontinuity at $x_0$. Though, it seems to me that this argument sort of proves IVT, so...

Comment: @CameronWilliams You have $x_n = f^n(x_0)$. Pick a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $x_{n_k} \to \xi$. Then $f(\xi) = \lim f(x_{n_k}) = \lim f^{n_k+1}(x_0) = \lim x_{n_k+1}$.But why $\lim x_{n_k+1} = \xi$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Your argument can't work that easy. You only invoke compactness, but the result is false if $f$ is defined on a compact set which is not connected.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d(x) = x - f(x)$ and $g(x) = \lvert d(x) \rvert$. Both functions are continuous.

$g([a,b])$ is compact, hence it attains its minimum $m \ge 0$ at some $\xi \in [a,b]$.

Assume that $m > 0$. Then $q(x) = d(x)/g(x)$ is well-defined and continuous. We have $\lvert q(x) \rvert \equiv 1$, thus $q(x) \in \{-1,+1\}$ for all $x$. We conclude that the preimages $q^{-1}(\pm 1)$ are disjoint open subsets of $[a,b]$. Hence one of these sets must be empty since $[a,b]$ is connected. In other words, $q(x) \equiv c \in \{-1,+1\}$. Thus
$$d(x) = cg(x) .$$
If $c = +1$, then $a - f(a) = d(a) = g(a) \ge m > 0$, i.e. $f(a) < a$ which is impossible.

If $c = -1$, then $b - f(b) = d(b) = -g(b) \le -m < 0$, i.e. $f(b) > b$ which is impossible.

Therefore $m > 0$ leads to a contradiction and we conclude $m = 0$. Hence $\xi$ is a fixed point of $f$.

**Edited:**

The use of $g(x)$ seems to be artificial and unnecessary. It was an attempt to use the hint in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this one, and their solutions, are so deeply interwoven with the intermediate value theorem, and it itself is such a *fundamental result*, the proof of which depends on *fundamental properties* of the reals $\Bbb R$ and its usual topology, that addressing such problems as this almost inevitability leads to the IVT or an equivalent.  Here I will use the connectedness of the interval $[a, b]$, which may also be used to prove the IVT--see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

So let

$f:[a, b] \to [a, b] \tag 1$

be continuous; if we assume

$\not \exists x \in [a, b], \; f(x) = x, \tag 2$

then we must indeed have

$f(a) > a, \; f(b) < b; \tag 3$

thus the continuous function

$g(x) = f(x) - x \tag 4$

satisfies

$g(a) > 0, \; g(b) < 0, \tag 5$

and

$g(x) \ne 0, \; \forall x \in [a, b]. \tag 6$

We next introduce the two sets

$A = \{x \in [a, b], \; g(x) > 0\} \tag 7$

and

$B = \{x \in [a, b], \; g(x) < 0\}; \tag 8$

it follows from (5) that

$A \ne \emptyset \ne B; \tag 9$

the continuity of $g(x)$ implies that $A$ and $B$ are open; furthermore,

$A \cap B = \emptyset, \tag{10}$

since $g(x)$ takes on opposite signs on $A$ and $B$; finally, $g(x) \ne 0$ implies every $x \in [a, b]$ is in either $A$ or $B$; thus

$A \cup B = [a, b]. \tag{11}$

We have now exhibited $[a, b]$ as a disjoint union of the two opens $A$ and $B$; but this contradicts the connectedness of $[a, b]$; therefore we must have some $x \in [a, b]$ with

$g(x) = f(x) - x = 0; \tag{12}$

that is,

$\exists x \in [a, b], \; f(x) = x. \tag{13}$

***Note Added in Edit, Tuesday 17 September 2019 9:58 AM PST:***  I fail to see how the compactness of the interval $[a, b]$ is essential to this demonstration.  *Connectedness*, yes; compactness, ***???***.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Even the use of $g(x) = f(x) - x$ is unnecessary. The sets $A = \{ x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) > x \}$ and $B = \{ x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) < x \}$ are obviously open in $[a,b]$. Thus the hint in the question does not seem to be valuable.

Comment: @PaulFrost:  not abosutely necessary, but I thought it made for a clearer presentation.  Cheers!

Comment: You are right, it is clearer as you did it. The reason for my comment was that the OP insisted on using $g(x) = \lvert x -  f(x) \rvert$. I cannot see why this function should have any advantage in comparison with your approach. The "minimal" approach would be to avoid using any auxiliary function. Anyway, the essential ingredient in the proof ist the  connectedness of intervals, and this cannot be avoided.

Comment: Concerning your note: The result is wrong for non-compact intervals. Your proof breaks down since at least one of $f(a), f(b)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Lewis has pointed out in his answer, the IVT can be regarded as an immediate consequence of the connectedness of intervals.

Let us have a systematic look at the relationship between connectedness, fixed point property and IVT.

Proposition 1. The following are equivalent for a compact subset $C \subset \mathbb R$:

1. $C$ is connected.
2. Each continuous map $f : C \to C$ has a fixed point.

Note that this does not involve the notion of an interval.

$1. \Rightarrow 2.$ : Since $C$ is compact, $m_+ = \max C, m_- = \min C$ are well-defined points of $C$. Let $C_+ = \{ x \in C \mid x < f(x) \}$, $C_- = \{ x \in C \mid x > f(x) \}$, $C_0 = \{ x \in C \mid x = f(x) \}$. Then $C$ is the disjoint union of $C_+, C_-, C_0$. It is easy to verify that $C_+, C_-$ are open in $C$. Now assume that $C_0 = \emptyset$. Then, since $C$ is connected, either $C_+ = C$ or $C_- = C$. If $C_+ = C$ we have $m_+ < f(m_+) \in C$ which is impossible, and if $C_- = C$ we have $m_- > f(m_-) \in C$ which is also impossible. We conclude that $C_0$ must be non-empty.

$2. \Rightarrow 1.$ : Assume that $C$ is not connected. Then $C = U \cup V$ with disjoint non-empty open $U, V \subset C$. Choose $u  \in U,v \in V$ and define $f : C \to C, f(x) = \begin{cases} v & x  \in U \\ u & x \in V \end{cases} \quad$. This is a continuous map without a fixed point, a contradiction.

Now we come to *intervals*. A subset $J \subset \mathbb R$ is an interval if any number that lies between two numbers in $J$ also belongs to $J$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics).

Fact 1. Each interval is connected.

The (a bit technical) proof is well-known.

Fact 2. Each connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is an interval.

This is obvious. If $J$ is connected and $a < \xi  < b$ with $a, b \in J$, then if $\xi \notin J$ we would get $C = J \cap (-\infty,\xi) \cup J \cap (\xi,\infty)$ which is impossible.

With these two facts we can prove

Proposition 2. The following are equivalent for a subset $C \subset \mathbb R$:

1. $C$ is compact and connected.
2. $C$ is a closed interval $[a,b]$.
3. Each continuous map $f : C \to C$ has a fixed point.

$1.$ and $2.$ are clearly equivalent and imply $3$.

$3. \Rightarrow 1.$ : Assume that $C$ is not connected or not compact. If it is not connected, then the proof of Proposition 1 produces a contradiction. So it remains to consider a connected, but not compact $C$. It must be an open or half-open interval (which may be bounded or unbounded). If $C = \langle a,\infty)$, where $\langle$ stands for $[$ or $($, then $f : C \to C, f(x) = x+1$, does not have a fixed point. If $C = \langle a,b)$, then define a homeomorphism $h : C \to \langle 0,\infty), h(x) = \dfrac{x-a}{b-x}$. Now $f(x) = h^{-1}(h(x) +1)$ does not have a fixed point. The other cases are treated similar and show that our assumption leads to a contradiction.

So far we did not explicitly consider images of connected sets under continuous maps.

Fact 3. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces. If $X$ is connected, then $f(X)$ is connected.

This is well-known.

Fact 4. Let $f : X \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous map. If $X$ is connected, then $f(X)$ is an interval.

This follows from Facts 2 and 3. It can also be viewed as a generalization of Fact 2 (the latter is obtained from Fact 4 by considering the subspace-inclusion $i : C \to \mathbb R$). Fact 4 can alternatively be proved as Fact 2 (without using Fact 3): Let $a < \xi < b$ with $a, b \in f(X)$. If $\xi \notin f(X)$, then we get $X = U \cup V$, where $U = f^{-1}((-\infty,\xi))$ and $V = f^{-1}((\xi,\infty))$ are nonempty open subsets of $X$. This is impossible.

Proposition 3. The following are equivalent for a subset $C \subset \mathbb R$:

1. $C$ is connected.
2. $C$ is an interval.
3. For each continuous $f : C \to \mathbb R$, the set $f(C)$ is connected.
4. For each continuous $f : C \to \mathbb R$, the set $f(C)$ is an interval.
5. (IVT for $C$) For each continuous $f : C \to \mathbb R$, if $a, b \in C$ and $y$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then $y \in f(C)$.

$1. \Leftrightarrow 2.$ and $3. \Leftrightarrow  4.$ are reformulations of Facts 1,2.

$4. \Leftrightarrow 5.$ is obvious by the definition of an interval.

$5. \Rightarrow 1.$ : We can use the same proof as in Proposition 1, $2. \Rightarrow 1.$

In my opinion Propositions 1,2 are independent from the IVT. Their proofs are based only on compactness and connectedness and the characterization of intervals as connected subsets of $\mathbb  R$, but do not invoke Fact 3 or Fact 4. The proof of the IVT is based on connectedness, the characterization of intervals as connected subsets of $\mathbb  R$ and Fact 3 resp. Fact 4. Putting it bold and simple: The IVT is a special case of Fact 4.

Thus, your request of giving a proof "without using the IVT" should be interpreted in the sense "without using Fact 3 resp. Fact 4". This applies to all previous answers **except my first answer**.

**Remark:**

Usually the IVT is stated in the following form:

If $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then for each $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ there exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = y$.

This is the IVT for closed intervals $C$, but this special case immediately implies the IVT for arbitrary intervals $C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(a) = a$ or $f(b) = b$, we are done. So let us assume that $f(a) > a$ and $f(b) < b$. Define $g(x) = x - f(x)$. This is a continuous map, hence $J = g([a,b])$ is a (compact) interval. We have $g(a) < 0$ and $g(b) > 0$. Since $[g(a),g(b)] \subset J$, we see that $0  \in J$.

Comment: I said specifically that I'm not supposed to use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: In your question you say that the image of $[a,b]$ under a continuous $g$ is a compact interval. This is in fact a version of the IVT, but then you should delete  the whole argument from your question.

Comment: I mean IVT is a corollary of the fact that the continuous image of a connected set is connected, so I feel like using that is different from invoking the the IVT on the function you suggest. Also why would Carothers give $g(x) = \lvert x - f(x)\rvert$ as a hint if you're actually supposed to use $g(x) = x - f(x)$

Comment: In fact $g([a,b])$ is a compact connected set if $g$ is continuous. It is easy to see that connected  subsets of $\mathbb R$ must be intervals, and this implies the IVT. But your question suggests that you regard the fact the $g([a,b])$ is an interval as independent from the IVT (otherwise you should delete this fact). If so, my argument is correct without using IVT although it works with a diifferent $g$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but your argument is identical to the standard proof using the intermediate value theorem which is not the solution I am looking for

Comment: Final comment: For the benefit of the reader please clarify explicitly (by editing your question) whether you allow to invoke the fact that continuous images of compact intervals are compact intervals